# Problem with aysmptote. DVIPS cannot find the header file

Tags: asymptote, dvips

This problem seems to be basically a dvips problem, but I am facing it when I try to use truetype fonts in asymptote.  The following is the asymptote file with tex preamble commands that enable me to use true type fonts in pdflatex.

```
settings.outformat="eps";
 texpreamble("\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}");
 texpreamble("\renewcommand{\familydefault}{arial}");
 texpreamble("\usepackage{mathastext}");
 texpreamble("\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{T1}{arial}{m}{n}");
import graph; size(9cm,0cm);
import patterns; 
add("myhatch",hatch(1.5mm,(1,1)));
add("myhatch1",hatch(1.5mm,(1,0)));
add("myhatch2",hatch(1.5mm,(1,3))); 
real labelscalefactor = 0.5; /* changes label-to-point distance */
pen dps = linewidth(0.7) + fontsize(10); defaultpen(dps); /* default pen style */ 
pen dotstyle = black; /* point style */ 
real xmin = -2.954424000000014, xmax = 10.5, ymin = -4.18462, ymax = 9.84868;  /* image dimensions */
Label laxis; laxis.p = fontsize(10); 
string blank(real x) {return "";} 
xaxis(xmin, xmax, Ticks(laxis, blank, Step = 2, Size = 2),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
yaxis(ymin, ymax, Ticks(laxis, blank, Step = 2, Size = 2),EndArrow(6), above = true); /* draws axes; NoZero hides '0' label */ 
 /* draw figures */
real f1 (real x) {return sqrt(4*2*x);} 
draw(graph(f1,0.0,xmax), linewidth(1) + black); 
real f2 (real x) {return -sqrt(4*2*x);} 
draw(graph(f2,0.0,xmax), linewidth(1) + black); 
real f3 (real x) {return x^(2)/(4*2);} 
draw(graph(f3,xmin,xmax), linewidth(1) + black); 
fill(graph(f1,0,8)..graph(f3,8,0)..cycle,pattern("myhatch1"));
 /* dots and labels */
dot((8,8),linewidth(4pt) + dotstyle); 
label("$A$", (8,8), 2NW * labelscalefactor); 
label("$0$",(0,0),SW);
label("$4ay=x^2$",(8.5,9.2),W);
label("$y^2=4ax$",(8.2,7.9),E);
clip((xmin,ymin)--(xmin,ymax)--(xmax,ymax)--(xmax,ymin)--cycle); 
 /* end of picture */
```

When I try to compile the file with asymptote, I get the following error message:

> dvips: ! Couldn't find header file: arial.ttf
>   /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10:
>   runtime: shipout failed

I created the following latex file as MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{arial}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{T1}{arial}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
    This is a minimal working example for arial.  Here is some maths. $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.
\end{document}
```

This compiles correctly if  I use pdflatex.  If I take the dvi->ps route, I get the following dvips error message.

> Process started: dvips -o "arial-mew-other".ps "arial-mew-other".dvi
>
> This is dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software
>   (www.radicaleye.com)
>
> ' TeX output 2019.06.17:1242' -> arial-mew-other.ps
>
> /usr/local/bin/dvips: ! Couldn't find header file: arial.ttf
>
> Process exited with error(s)

The command

> kpsewhich -all winfonts.map

produces the following output:

> /opt/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/winfonts/winfonts.map
>   /opt/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map
>   /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map

What can be the problem?

Comment: afaik dvips can't handle ttf-fonts directly. If its map file contains lines which tries to embed arial.ttf this is simply wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer.  Thanks for the response.  If I include the asymptote file in a latex file using \asyinclude{file_name} command and run pdflatex, it works fine.  But, I want to create a standalone file that I can use in a word document. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If word can input pdf you could use the standalone class to create it.

Comment: For a standalone file, have you tried 
`settings.tex="pdflatex";`
instead of `settings.outformat="eps";` ?

Comment: @g.kov Thanks.  This option works.